# save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'owner'

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

models.py

```
class Video(models.Model):
obj = models.FileField()
owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
dis = models.TextField()
title = models.ForeignKey(Title,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=0)
def __str__(self):
    return self.dis
```

serializers.py

```
class VideoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
#owner = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False, read_only=True)
class Meta:
    model = Video
    fields = ['obj','dis','owner','title']

def save(self,validated_data):
    request = self.context.get("request")
    v = Video(
        obj = validated_data.get('obj'),
        dis = validated_data.get('dis'),
        owner = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user),
        )
    v.save()
    return v
    

   

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    request = self.context.get("request")
    instance.title = validated_data.get('title',instance.title)
    instance.dis = validated_data.get('dis', instance.dis)
    if instance.owner == request.user:
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

views.py

```
class VideoView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
serializer_class = VideoSerializer
queryset = Video.objects.all()

def perform_create(self, serializer):
    user = self.request.user
    serializer.save(owner=Profile.objects.get(user=user))
```

hi guys! i try to save a model in database with DRF serializers & i get an error....
i will be thankfull if you help me.my error is in save() method in serializers

Answer (score 0):

You should not override the `save` argument in the method definition. Instead use this:

```
def save(self):
    owner = self.validated_data.get('owner')
    ...
```

Ref:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-save-directly